# C# System.Net.Http.StringContent() gives exception during the run time

Tags: c#

We have the following piece of code where we use constructor of System.Net.Http.StringContent(). This following code is executed by multiple threads in my application.

```
public static HttpContent GetContent(this object model)
    {
        var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });           
        var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        return content;
    }
```

We are getting Null reference exception in the execution of above code. "body"
param is just a string variable which we confirmed it to be not null. The following is the stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object. at System.Text.Encoding.get_WebName() at
> System.Net.Http.StringContent..ctor(String content, Encoding encoding,
> String mediaType) at
> AW.Api.Client.Extensions.HttpExtensions.GetContent(Object model,
> String contentType)

StringContent() is trying to access the WebName property of Encoding.cs and on seeing the library code of Encoding.cs,
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,00987bab2ca262fa

We can notice that while accessing the property "WebName", a private field "dataItem" is being referenced after a null-check. Can anyone please help in understanding what might go wrong here?  Is there a possibility of race condition where "dataItem" is being referenced by one thread while other thread setting it to null.

Comment: You mentioned multiple threads, is `body` thread safe? is there a chance its being set to null ect? if not, then you may have found a bug, if so you might want to make a github post about it

Comment: Amen to michael's comment - we really need to see more about the lifecycle and scope of the body variable

Comment: Thank you.  `body` is local variable which we are setting it to a non-null value and it's thread safe.   Also, if `body` was null, StringContent() would have given ArugmentNullException straightaway. So that also one more pointer for `body` not being null.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  This happened only once in our build pipeline and resulted in a test failure.

Comment: `"body" param is just a string variable which we confirmed it to be not null` If it happened only once, how exactly did you confirm it wasn't null?

Comment: @mjwills As I mentioned above, `body` is local variable which we are setting it to a non-null value and it's thread safe. Also, if body was null, StringContent() would have given ArugmentNullException straightaway. So that also one more proof for body not being null.

Comment: .NET Core or Framework?

Comment: It is .NET Framework.

Comment: The problem is here, you cant reproduce the error. We have nothing to test... We cant rule things in or out. And even if we some how gave you the right answer, you cant prove it either way

Comment: The problem could _theoretically_ occur if there were concurrent calls to `GetDataItem` and your one succeeded and then the other failed and overwrite `_dataItem` with `null` before you tried to read from it. Hell of an edge case though.

Comment: My money is its something to do with a header, and that it doesn't happen in StringContent constructor and is likely on send. but that is a total guess and a completely futile statement

Answer (score -1):

It seems like this code line not the true exception line.

Try to check the LINE REFERENCED THE VARIABLE "content"

Here is the code example ,I assume you use System.Net.Http.HttpClient

```
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //                              below is the variable content
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(true);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new FileNotFoundException();
                var responseContent = response.Content;
                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
            }
```